# How do I link annexure numbers in a Word document automatically if annexures are added?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

in typing legal documents, there are many annexures specified throughout the document. How do I link the annexures to each other to automatically update if annexures are added or deleted, i.e.

Annexure **A**
.....
Annexure **B**
.....
[insert new Annexure *C*]

Annexure **C**  [Annexure *C* to become **D**]

Comment: You may want to give more detail and perhaps a link to a sample problem document. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask. I am a lawyer and am unfamiliar with the term annexure. Our local practice may refer to these as attachments or even appendices. On the other hand, if my response did meet your need, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am a lawyer.

### Consider using a Sequence field.

Here is a link to the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be) on that field. The following is an excerpt.

> When you view the Seq field in your document, the syntax looks like
> this:
>
> `{ SEQ Identifier [Bookmark ] [Switches ] }`
>
> Instructions
>
> Identifier
>
> The name you assign to a series of items to number. The name must
> start with a letter and is limited to 40 characters (letters, numbers,
> and underscores). For example, the name for a series of tables might
> be "tables."
>
> Bookmark
>
> Include a bookmark name to refer to an item elsewhere in the document.
> For example, to cross-reference an illustration, mark the Seq field
> numbering for that illustration with the bookmark "Pic2," and then
> insert a cross-reference to it using { SEQ illust Pic2 }.

Switches

> \c
>
> Repeats the closest preceding sequence number. This is useful for
> inserting chapter numbers in headers or footers.
>
> \h
>
> Hides the field result. Use it to refer to a Seq field in a
> cross-reference without printing the number. For example, you might
> want to refer to a numbered chapter but not print the chapter number.
> The \h switch doesn't hide the field result if a Format (*) switch is
> also present.
>
> \n
>
> Inserts the next sequence number for the specified items. This is the
> default.
>
> \r n
>
> Resets the sequence number to the specified number n. For example, {
> SEQ figure \r 3 } starts figure numbering at 3.
>
> \s
>
> Resets the sequence number at the heading level following the "s". For
> example, { SEQ figure \s 2 } starts numbering at the Heading 2 style.

I write about it in my chapter (from the Legal Users Guide) on [Numbering](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields) in terms of Interrogatory numbering.

> Sequence fields are the first method that Word developed for automatic
> numbering and, in the words of John McGhie, the most robust. They are
> virtually unbreakable.